# How do you intake a column of values in R to produce an 'all minus all' matrix?

Tags: r, function, subtraction

```
#sample df
label <- c("A", "B", "C")
value <- c(1,5,3)
example <- cbind(label, value)
```

how do I write a function such that
function(example)
gives an output following:

```
     A    B    C
A    0   -4   -2
B    4    0    2
C    2   -2    0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugFVB.png)

Comment: `cbind` here doesn't make `data.frame`s, it makes `matrix` objects that turn your `value` column into character rather than numeric. You want `data.frame(label, value)` I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a case for `outer` although I  would NOT make an example with `cbind` because that will coerce the numeric `value` object to character within `example`, because `cbind` creates matrices when given only atomic vectors and matrices can have only one class. Instead make the matrix first and then apply the labels to that entity

```
outer(value, value, FUN="-")
#----------
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0   -4   -2
[2,]    4    0    2
[3,]    2   -2    0

example <- outer(value, value, FUN="-")
?matrix
rownames(example) <- label
colnames(example) <- label
```

Another way to do this (and more compactly) would be:

```
> names(value) <- label
> value
A B C 
1 5 3 
> outer(value, value, FUN="-")
  A  B  C
A 0 -4 -2
B 4  0  2
C 2 -2  0
```

And as @thelatemail says one can use `setNames`, but he was assuming that these values were in a dataframe object which would only be the case if you had earlier accepted  his comment to the question.

Comment: Could get the labels happening with `o <- setNames(example$value, example$label); outer(o, o, \`-\`)` or similar too. Assuming they intended to make a `data.frame` not a matrix.